# The target "ResolveTagHelperRazorGenerateInputs" does not exist in the project

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, msbuild, visual-studio-2017

I am getting the following error when i try to build an AspNetCore Web Application targeting netcoreapp2.2.

> Error MSB4057 The target "ResolveTagHelperRazorGenerateInputs" does not exist in the project. C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\2.2.103\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor\build\netstandard2.0\Sdk.Razor.CurrentVersion.targets

I have tried the following:

- clear cache on vs according to [this post](https://www.matteopozzani.com/visual-studio-cache-cleanup/)
- update vs2017 to 15.9.5
- reinstall net core sdks
- reinstall vs

Nothing helped. I first got the error during an upgrade from core 2.1 to core 2.2 on a different project, and it's possible that by mistake edited the 
Sdk.Razor.CurrentVersion.targets file. From that moment on, i keep getting this error on any project that targets core 2.2 (even new ones).

Does anyone encountered this problem or have any clues about solving it?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After long battles it figured out to be a problem with VS NuGet Package Manager.
All I had to do was:

VS > Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Clear All NuGet Cache(s).

Comment: thanks. this worked for me. i was running into this issue after upgrading a 2.1 project to 2.2

Answer (score 4):

For me the solution was as follows:

In Visual Studio

1. Right click on each project and click "Unload Project"
2. Right click on each project and click "Reload Project"

Answer (score 1):

The Following Link was my solution. I also struggled to get this fixed.

Just copy the files from the **NetStandard2.0** folder from GitHub then replace it with you Directory from the same location.

Hopefully this helps someone.!

> **Here is the Answered Link**:
>   https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/cafc9823-eb61-46f7-8489-007242ef2ad2/target-quotresolvetaghelperrazorgenerateinputsquot-does-not-exist-in-the-project?forum=msbuild
>
> **Here is the GitHub Link**
>   https://github.com/aspnet/Razor/tree/master/src/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Razor/build/netstandard2.0

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue during the Azure build pipeline process, and clearing the NuGet package cache resolved the issue.

**Solution:**
I used a dotnet tasks with "custom" to issue the following command before NuGet package restore task:

**command:**
dotnet nuget locals global-packages -c

[Screenshot shows the build pipeline task](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sHR2K.png)